# Keep only newest records using DQL

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have a symfony app with doctrine. There is a table like:

`+--------+---------------------+-------+
|   user  |      log_date       |  foo  |
+---------+---------------------+-------+
|   john  | 2018-03-20 22:59:18 |   58  |
|   kyle  | 2018-04-11 13:45:02 |   22  |
|   paul  | 2018-11-08 22:19:16 |   41  |
|   kyle  | 2018-08-14 09:39:26 |   19  |
|   fred  | 2018-03-28 06:08:31 |   24  |
|   john  | 2018-01-21 11:52:17 |   81  |
|   ...   |          ...        |  ...  |
+---------+---------------------+-------+`

A cron should execute a symfony command to delete all records but keep the latest 10 of every user. Can this be done using DQL or do I have to use an SQL (sub-)query?

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this in entity repository can get all the entries for the user except the last 10

```
public function getAllExceptLatest($user)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->andWhere('t.logDate <= :logDate')
        ->orderBy('t.logDate', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter(':logDate', $this->getLatestDate($user))
        ->setFirstResult(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}

public function getLatestDate($user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select('MAX(e.logDate)')
        ->andWhere('e.user = :user')
        ->setParameter(':user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

And in controller you can use

```
   public function keepLatest(){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $userRepo = $em->getRepository(User::class);

        $users = $userRepo->findAll();
        foreach ($users as $u) {
            $records = $userRepo->getAllExceptLatest($u);
            foreach ($records as $r)
            $em->remove($r);
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
```

I didn't test this, but in mine apps similar methods works fine